# How Spotify and Google’s Waze integration component works?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-extension, ios-urlsheme

Lately, I have seen that Waze shows a Spotify's button on top of its map.
I was wondering how does it work?

[image]

At first, when you press the Spotify button you are getting redirected to Spotify via an url-scheme (probably spotify://waze?example) then you approve the use and get back with a session (with a waze://) I guess.

So I understand the binding process but how does the Spotify component work inside the Waze app. Let's say I'm pressing the pause button or next song. What's happen?

One thing I have noticed. To resume playing go to the next song or add to favorites they are using some other functionality that I don't recognize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's two-way integration between the services according to the [Waze Official Blog](https://blog.waze.com/2017/03/rock-road-with-waze-and-spotify.html) + [iOS](https://blog.waze.com/2017/09/more-waze-to-rocktheroad.html)

Also, Spotify has [Spotify iOS SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/) which allows you to implement some features in your own apps.

Comment: I understand that but technically if I have my own two separate apps and I wish to integrate between them, what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure, but they can have some kind of an API that provides this kind of communication between two apps using external services plus deep-linking. Also, you can check the  [Inter-App Communication documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

Comment: Oh, the link is not available. I was sure it is an extension of the Spotify app

Comment: Well, it's also possible that it is the Spotify extension, but it's definitely not public and wasn't mentioned in their SDK documentation.

Comment: I understand. Let say you have your own two apps. How would you do it?